# Permissions Error Registering Assembly

Tags: visual-studio, com, interop

I've waited a long time for concensus on moving from IIS to the built in web server for debugging our web application, one of the main reasons being that I don't always have to run VS as admin.

We now have a COM dll included (exported by) in the solution, and on build it, VS tries to register this and complains because my regular user doesn't have the required registry access.  Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine the parent registry key that is denying access and change its permissions. You can use regmon from sysinternals to determine where the permissions failure occurs:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896652.aspx

And you can use regedit to change the permissions (right click on a key and choose permissions... entry). On win2000 you need to use regedt32 (regular regedit does not have permissions menu entry).